# REST adapter to work with https

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I am writing an REST adapter in Express that translates incoming REST calls to another REST API as exposed by the northbound device. So essentially, a client device is sending a request to a REST API exposed by the adapter and the adapter sends a REST request to an another device. So the adapter is both a REST server for the client devices as well as a REST client to the northbound device.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {           
        request('URL'', function (error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("Sent to MOS");
                console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
            }
        })
    });

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using the request module. My northbound device is exposing an https REST API. When I insert the **https** (mind the 's') REST API call in the URL section in the code above I don't get an answer back from the northbound device.

It works well if the 'URL' above is pointing to an https website, like https://www.httpsnow.org/. Also, when I use the https REST API in POSTMAN or from my browser on the same device, I get a proper response.

So I don't understand why it would work from POSTMAN, but not from my code. From the broser I had to accept a certificate first so I guess the issue is that my code is not authenticated, but how to build that authentication in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a trivial error - your server opens a connection to a HTTPS server, the server's certificate appears to be invalid, handshake is refused and you get an error instead of response.

Luckily, [request](https://github.com/request/request) supports custom HTTPS certificates(i.e. a certificate that would be shown as invalid will show as valid) natively.

You can use the `agentOptions` option for this. Download the certificate you had to accept with the browser(they should provide one in their docs) and save it as `ca.cert.pem`(or some other extension, depending on what they provide) in the same folder as the Node.js app you're building.

Then use it like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

request({
    url: 'https://api.some-server.com/',
    agentOptions: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.cert.pem') //Note: This will load the ca synchronously. Avoid doing this in production.
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
  if(error){
    console.warn(error); //If an error occurred, you'll be informed
    return; //Won't run the rest of the function
  }

  if(response.statusCode === 200){
    //Do whatever you want
  }
});
```

Comment: I downloaded the certificate and use the code you suggested, but I got an error: [Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames]. I had to add rejectUnauthorized:false to the options which I understood is a real security breach. Doesn't matter for my purpose as this is for a internal corporate app, but would be nice to understand how to deal with this properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with the northbound web server configuration and not with the request library itself. Try changing the user-agent string to something else:

```
var opts = {
  url: 'URI',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
  }
};

request(opts, function (err, res, body) {
  // Do stuff
});
```